# How to block direct access to files upload in edd folder

Tags: redirect, nginx, user-access, shared-hosting

My site server on a shared web hosting service with **Cpanel** and **NGINX**. I want to block direct access to files upload in the easy digital downloads upload folder ( wp-content/uploads/edd ). I use [.htaccess](http://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/247-modifying-edd-htaccess-file-rules) but it's not work. I want to use [custom redirect rule](http://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/683-protecting-file-downloads-on-wp-engine) but i don't know how can i do that in Cpanel.

Comment: don't use a shared host that uses nginx. nginx is not a good web server for shared hosting as you can't have a per site configuration without the involvment of the system admin.

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun. I can change the web server. In your opinion what is better for wordpress and edd, LiteSpeed or Apache?

Comment: on shared hosting I think apache. In the minimum you will have much more tutorials available for you.